# Good RoR Gravatar gem/plugin and detect if the gravatar account exists or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I'm currently using mdeering's gravatar_image_tag plugin to get gravatar images for users but my dilemma is to try to detect in the code if the user has a gravatar:

If he does then display the gravatar image.
If not, then display a local default image file on my server.

I'm open to using other plugins if they offer this functionality.

Please provide code examples.  They help me learn the best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need gems/plugins. This [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/244-gravatar) explains what you need step-by-step. It comes down to using the following helper method:

```
def avatar_url(user)
  default_url = "#{root_url}images/guest.png"
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48&d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helper method to check if a user has already a gravatar image :

The trick is to get gravatar image with a false default image and then check header response.
It's achieved with the Net::HTTP ruby library.

```
def gravatar?(user)
        gravatar_check = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.gravatar_email.downcase)}.png?d=404"
        uri = URI.parse(gravatar_check)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
        response = http.request(request)
        if (response.code.to_i == 404)
            return false
        else
            return true
        end 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Gravtastic gem should come to your rescue. Its fairly straightforward - you may peruse through its README. The Gem's github [link](https://github.com/chrislloyd/gravtastic)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm extremely late to the party but the gravatar_image_tag gems does have the options that you need to accomplish this very easily.

You can [configure your default image globally](https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag#configuration) in your application like so:

```
# config/initializers/gravatar_image_tag.rb
GravatarImageTag.configure do |config|   
  # Set this to use your own default gravatar image rather then serving up Gravatar's default image [ 'http://example.com/images/default_gravitar.jpg', :identicon, :monsterid, :wavatar, 404 ].
  config.default_image  = nil
end
```

Or on a [one off basis](https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag#setting-the-default-image-inline) like so:

```
gravatar_image_tag('junk', alt: 'Github Default Gravatar', gravatar: { default: 'https://assets.github.com/images/gravatars/gravatar-140.png' })
```